# Creating a next and previous button with simple JavaScript? If statement?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to do a simple back forward with a picture slider. I have gotten the next on the button, but need to create the function for back.

I cannot seem to get it and cannot remember with simple pure javascript. What would the if statement be? I assume the position needs to be changed to 0. Thank you for the advice.

For the forward I have:

```
  function Forward()
xxxx[arrayPosition].className = "thumb"; 
     mm[arrayPosition].className = "yyy"; 

        if(arrayPosition == xxxx.length - 1){
            arrayPosition = 0; }

          else{
           arrayPosition = arrayPosition + 1; in memory  }


        xxxx[arrayPosition].className = "thumb active";     
       mm[arrayPosition].className = "yyy active"; }
```

Comment: for the backward, you subtract 1, but set to xxxx.length - 1 if 0

Comment: xxxx[arrayPosition].className = "thumb"; 
  mm[arrayPosition].className = "yyy"; 
  
  if(arrayPosition == xxxx.length 0){
   arrayPosition = 1; }

    else{
     arrayPosition = arrayPosition -1;
  }
  
  xxxx[arrayPosition].className = "thumb active";   mm[arrayPosition].className = "yyy active"; }

Comment: That? Sorry, just trying to learn JavaScript and not sure what I'm doing.

Comment: no not quite - the answer below looks right

Answer (score 0):

When going back, you would want to check if the current `arrayPosition` is `0`. If so, the array position should be updated to be the last index. For example:

```
if(arrayPosition === 0) {
    arrayPosition = xxxx.length - 1;
} else {
    arrayPosition -= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function Forward(){

     xxxx[arrayPosition].className = "thumb"; 
     mm[arrayPosition].className = "yyy"; 

        if((arrayPosition == xxxx.length - 1)||
           (arrayPosition == 0)){
            arrayPosition = 0; 
        }else{

            arrayPosition = arrayPosition + 1; 
        }


        xxxx[arrayPosition].className = "thumb active";     
       mm[arrayPosition].className = "yyy active"; 
       }
```